# How to get data from firebase database with GET

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase database as my rest api and I am POSTed data in the following way

```
https://doctorapp-b8180.firebaseio.com/app.json
```

POST body

```
{"name":"facebook"}
```

It is very simple, it has one node called **app** that has child called **name**.

But when I POST what is happening is that its adding some sort of key. which looks like this.

**KjIoN-2vKwHFHwwKf9y**

Now, I need to do GET request and I need app with name facebook, but I cannot get that element because of the key POST request added. This is my GET request

```
https://doctorapp-b8180.firebaseio.com/app/facebook/name.json
```

This is returning null. But when I add the key like the following, its working

```
https://doctorapp-b8180.firebaseio.com/app/KjIoN-2vKwHFHwwKf9y/facebook/name.json
```

the thing is I want to GET data with name parameter not without key. Is it possible. Besides when I add an element I do not know it's key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a push key. You'll have to query for the data you want.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering)

Unable to test this, but try a query like this:

```
https://doctorapp-b8180.firebaseio.com/app.json?orderBy="name"&startAt="facebook"&endAt="facebook"
```

Make a note of this from the docs (emphasis mine):

> Add Indexing to your Firebase Realtime Database Rules: **If you're using orderBy in your app, you need to define the keys you will be indexing on via the .indexOn rule in your Firebase Realtime Database Rules.** Read the documentation on the .indexOn rule for more information.

So you'll need to configure a rule for that.